# Adding additional parameters to image classification in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator, digital-image-processing

I have an RGB ortho rectified Image and I have another grid data with Elevation values.

However, an image with only three bands does not give a good classification of landcover, so it is important to add additional information e.g. pattern or elevation data from another dataset.

I only have access to ArcGIS software so I wish to know how I can do this in ArcGIS for Desktop?

[image: The following Image will be the Input of classification.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to merge the DEM with the imagery as a fourth band?  I don't think elevation is a valid dataset for land use classification.  However, as you indicated, the pattern of the land derived from the DEM might be better.  You may want to look into **[Composite Bands](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009p000000)**.  That will add your land pattern file as a new band to your imagery.  The composite bands is available to all license levels of ArcGIS.

The ESRI documentation states that the tool:

> Creates a single raster dataset from multiple bands and can also
>   create a raster dataset using only a subset of bands.

Once you have that, you can use the **[Image Classification toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00nv00000008000000)**.

> The Image Classification toolbar provides a user-friendly environment
>   for creating training samples and signature files for supervised
>   classification. It also serves as a centralized location for
>   performing both supervised classification and unsupervised
>   classification.

However, this is only available with the **[Spatial Analyst extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_the_ArcGIS_Spatial_Analyst_extension/005900000001000000/)**.